Phaser 3, pause on minimize
I am creating an animation with phaser which contains a timer.
The issue occurs when I Alt-Tab or minimize the page as the timer keeps on running but the animation stops, so the GameObjects are not in sync with the timers.
I've looked through the config class of the phaser object and couldn't find any parameter related to this.
I also tried using this.game.loop.wake() when changing visibility but it doesn't seem to be working also (it still stops the animation while I'm not on the page)
create()
{
   //[...]
   this.setupVisibilityChangeListener();
}

setupVisibilityChangeListener() {
  document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
    this.game.loop.wake();
  });
}

EDIT 1
As requested here are some additional details
The project is a react project and initialize the game inside the useEffect of a certain page with the below config
useEffect(() => {
  //[...]
  const config: Phaser.Types.Core.GameConfig = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'phaser-container',
    width: width,
    height: height,
    transparent: true,
    scene: [new RaceScene(data, isMobile)],
    physics: {
      default: 'arcade',
      arcade: {
        debug: false,
        fps: 30,
      },
    },
    fps: {
      target: 30,
      forceSetTimeOut: true,
    },
    input: {
      touch: {
        capture: false,
      },
    },
  }

  const game = new Phaser.Game(config)
  //[...]
})

I'm using Phaser 3.80.1 that I installed with npm
I use the time from the time parameter in the update function and emit the event with a React Event Emitter like seen below
import animationEventEmitter from '<path>/animation.event'

update(time: number, delta: number): void {
  //[...]
  animationEventEmitter.emit('timeUpdate', time)
  //[...]
}

And here is the simple event emitter
import { EventEmitter } from 'events'

const animationEventEmitter = new EventEmitter()

export default animationEventEmitter 

No timeout or delay is used anywhere
As suggested I tried to add the below inside the create of the scene
this.game.events.on('visible', () =>{ 
  this.game.resume() 
});

this.game.events.on('hidden', () => {
  this.game.pause()
});

But the timer kept on moving even thought I alt-tab ed while the animation stopped...

If you use phaser Timer functions, this should not happen since, it uses the game clock. (link to documentation)
Are you maybe using setTimeout, setInterval or using timestamps? If so you could rewrite your code to use phaser time/timer functions.
Short Demo [Updated]:
(ShowCasing the timer, loosely based on official example)


class DemoScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  timedEvent;
    text;
    image;
    pauseCount;
    
    create () {
        this.text = this.add.text(32, 32);
        this.pauseCount = 0;

        this.timedEvent = this.time.addEvent({ delay: 2000, callback: this.onEvent, callbackScope: this, repeat: 4 });
        
         this.game.events.on('visible', () =>{  
             console.info('PAUSE END fired!');
             this.pause = false;
         });
         
         this.game.events.on('hidden', () => {  
             console.info('PAUSE START fired!');
             this.pause = true;
             this.pauseCount++;
         });
         
    }

    update (time) {
      if(this.pause){
          console.info(time)
          return
      }
      
        this.text.setText(`Event.progress: ${this.timedEvent.getProgress().toString().substr(0, 4)}\nEvent.repeatCount: ${this.timedEvent.repeatCount}\nPause Counter: ${this.pauseCount}`);
    }

    onEvent () {
      console.info('EVENT fired!');
    }
}

var config = {
    width: 540,
    height: 180,
    scene: DemoScene,
}; 

new Phaser.Game(config);

console.clear();
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>




Tip: If possible always opt for phaser function / features, before turning to vanilla javascript.

Update 2:
If your timer relies on the time parameter of the update function, time wll not stand still since as mentioned before, it starts with the start of the application. A "quick" solution could be to sum the pause-time and subtract it, from the time parameter:
create () {
    //[...]
    this.pauseTimeSum = 0; 
    this.game.events.on('visible', () =>{  
        this.pause = false;
        if ( this.pauseStart > 0 ){
            this.pauseTimeSum += Date.now() - this.pauseStart;
        }
    });
     
     this.game.events.on('hidden', () => {  
         this.pause = true;
         this.pauseStart = Date.now();
     });         
}

update(time: number, delta: number): void {
  //[...]
  animationEventEmitter.emit('timeUpdate', time - this.pauseTimeSum)
  //[...]
}

It's not nice but it is a quick & easy solution, if you need to use the time parameter.

Is the time parameter inside the update different than the one inside the scene?
I've been using the one inside the update
update(time: number, delta: number): void {
And on the contrary I would need the timer and the animation to keep going and not to stop when I'm alt-tabed

the time parameter in the update function is only number, that counts the milliseconds of the elapsed time since the start.  Depending on the usecase, there are different solutions, can you share more code in your question?  It's not clear to me, for what you are using the "timer" or the time parameter.

@A.JAlhorr Depending on the usecase you could use the events visible and hidden of the game object, to "pause" calls to  the update function or update the time-counter or do some other stuff (I updated my answer to showcase this).

Thank you for the update, unfortunately the time kept on moving forward while I added your suggestion this.game.resume() and this.game.pause(). Quick question: is this cdn the latest phaser version as the syntax was a little different from my end. I've updated my question further.

Yes it is the latest version, you can see this in the console. It is Version3.80.1.  Phaser has many ways to achieve the same result. I look at you updated question

@A.JAlhorr I updated my answer with a possible workaround.

Thank you, I guess I'll have to handle it like you're suggesting...
I guess eventually I should have my own timer class to handle the time inside the game like I usually do. It just felt to redundant to update it on every update that's why I tried to opt not to have a separate time class this time
